# Create Responsive iFrame

Tags: html, css

I created a responsive landing page in Markeo (a marketing automation software tool). Here's the URL Marketo provided: http://info.onvia.com/responsive.html

What I want to do it display that URL on my website (www.Onvia.com) and have it still be responsive. I think the only way to create an iFrame and bring in that URL from Marketo. My problem is when that URL is brought into the iFrame, it doesn't act as responsive on a mobile phone. I still have to zoom in to see the content.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/3LAat/334/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="h_iframe">
    <iframe  src="http://info.onvia.com/responsive.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body        {height:100%; margin:0;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%; margin:0;}
```

Comment: On desktop, it's creating a double set of scroll bars.

On mobile, it's not acting like a responsive page.

Comment: Go to http://info.onvia.com/xchange.html, it's 404 (page doesn't exist)

Comment: Sorry changed it to  info.onvia.com/responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
iframe, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html, body { height: 100vh; }
    iframe {
      height:350%;
      width:100%;
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://info.onvia.com/responsive.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```